# Create RDP session programmatically

Tags: windows, session, rdp

We have a remote support tool that allows us to connect to machines behind a NAT firewall. Once connected, we can choose to either connect to the console session or to any active RDP session from a list. We cannot connect to inactive/disconencted RDP sessions, and the tool has no way to create new loopback/redirected RDP sessions. What we would like to do is find a way to spawn these RDP sessions via a script or a small application so that the support tool can detect them and allow us to connect. The motivation to get this working is to be able to have multiple techs access the same server simultaneously (up to one active console session and two active RDP sessions, all at the same time, for a total of three techs).

If we log on to the console session of the target servers and then RDP to the loopback, we see the new RDP session in our support tool, which we can then select and connect to. The problem is that this RDP session creation depends on the console session. It also gives the console session access to the RDP session, and if the RDP window is minimized then the output/input for that session in our support tool is frozen. I was able to use the PS script Connect-Mstsc (mostly just a wrapper for mstsc.exe but with support for adding creds) to create RDP sessions from another random server on the remote internal network to the target server we want to create a new RDP session on. This works well from an automation standpoint but we have the same limitation described above - it only works if run interactively. If you run this from a SYSTEM shell remotely, the RDP session never appears in our support tool.

The remote support tool in question is ScreenConnect and our servers are all Windows, mostly 2012 R2, all AD environments. I think the core challenges to this solution are getting the RDP sessions created and active in a non-interactive fashion, and then preventing RDP from freezing the session input/output.